# CentOS suspicious process

Tags: linux, centos, process

One of my web server is running on CentOS and I have been spotted that one of the processes is taking almost all swap memory.
Mention process is:

> /opt/opsware/agent/bin/pyton
>   /opt/opsware/agent/pylibs/shadowbot/deamonbot.pyc --conf
>   /etc/opt/opsware/agent/agent.args

I've tried to google it but I can't find anything.
Process is not using CPU only memory.
Do you know that I can kill it without affecting any of web services?

Comment: I've a similar issue, what is this process anyway?

Answer (score 5):

That looks like the agent for Opsware or [HP's Server Automation](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/server-automation-software/) software.

Are you responsible for this system? If not, can you see if the responsible party knows what is happening?

From here, it seems like the system you're working on is part of a larger environment, which may have some monitoring or deployment tools installed.

Look in `/opt/opsware/` - This is well-known software that probably isn't there by accident or malicious means.

Comment: Thanks I have already rise a ticket with hosting company.